# CodeIgniter: Login user details not inserting properly

Tags: php

Please help me insert code is not working fine in facebook and google login user details

below is my model function

**#facebook insert code ..**

```
public function checkUser($data = array()){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $this->primaryKey);
    $this->db->from($this->tablename);
    $this->db->where(array('oauth_provider'=>$data['oauth_provider'],'oauth_uid'=>$data['oauth_uid']));
    $prevQuery = $this->db->get();
    $prevCheck = $prevQuery->num_rows();

    if($prevCheck > 0){
        $prevResult = $prevQuery->row_array();
        $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $update = $this->db->update($this->tablename,$data,array('id'=>$prevResult['id']));
        $userID = $prevResult['id'];
    }else{
        $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $insert = $this->db->insert($this->tablename,$data);
        $userID = $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    return $userID?$userID:FALSE;
}

This function insert twice and if oauth_uid already exists then it again insert I want if exists then only update  

***#google insert code..***
public function google_checkUser($data = array()){
    $this->db->select($this->primaryKey);
    $this->db->from($this->tablename);
    $this->db->where(array('oauth_provider'=>$data['oauth_provider'],'oauth_uid'=>$data['oauth_uid']));
    $prevQuery = $this->db->get();
    $prevCheck = $prevQuery->num_rows();

    if($prevCheck > 0){
        $prevResult = $prevQuery->row_array();
        $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $update = $this->db->update($this->tablename,$data,array('id'=>$prevResult['id']));
        $userID = $prevResult['id'];
    }else{
        $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $insert = $this->db->insert($this->tablename,$data);
        $userID = $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    return $userID?$userID:FALSE;
}
```

This works well but as I update the email it insert the facebook code 4 more time please help to solve this issue

Comment: when user hits the  facebbok or google link if he is allready exists in our database means no need to update again in database directly you can provide login for him and keep all the details in session...

Comment: yes but i want to update in db it always insert

Comment: my suggestion is check the $prevCheck  value whether you are getting correct value or not for existing user...